# Smaller margin on VB.NET Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts

Is there a way to customize the margin between the first bar chart and the Y-Axis?

I'm aware that there is the possibility to set IsMarginVisible to False:

```
.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = False
```

But I don't want to remove the margin completely, I just would like to adjust it a bit. In âddition, I would like to adjust the margin between the "ticks" and the label text. Here is an example:

*Here is how the chart looks right now*

[image: Old]

*And how it should look like (space in front and after the "ticks")*
[image: New]

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like that there is no margin property in the way I would have liked one. But I stumbled upon this article today: http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=869

My workaround was to set the MajorTickMark to the size of the ticks I wanted to have + the margin. Then I set the color to transparent.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorTickMark.Size = size
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

After that, I just added a HorizontalLineAnnotation for every row in the size and place I wanted.

```
Dim minValue As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea").AxisY.Minimum
Dim maxValue As Double = Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea").AxisY.Maximum
Dim iteration As Integer = CInt((Math.Abs(minValue) + Math.Abs(maxValue )) / interval)

For i As Integer = 0 To iteration
    Dim line As New HorizontalLineAnnotation()
    With line
        .AxisX = Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea").AxisX
        .AxisY = Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea").AxisY
        .AnchorX = 0
        .Y = i * interval - Math.Abs(minValue)
        .AnchorOffsetX = offset
        .Height = 0
        .LineWidth = 1
        .Width = (5 / Chart1.Width.Value * 1240)
        .LineColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128)
        End With
    Chart1.Annotations.Add(line)
Next
```

With this workaround, I got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 With Chart1.Series(0)

        .BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom
        .Color = Color.Magenta
        .BackSecondaryColor = Color.Purple
        .IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        .Points.DataBind(dtTest.DefaultView, "Month", "Bought", Nothing)
        *****The pixel point width******.CustomProperties = "DrawingStyle = Cylinder ,PixelPointWidth = 26"
    End With
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm already using the CustomProperty "PointWidth" which allows me to change the width of the single bars. But as I'm looking for how to customize the space, this answer doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

chart1.ChartAreas("Default").AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 2

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add manually some "blank spaces" into each Y value, converting them to a string like "50,000   "?

Comment: This would solve the problem with the spaces in front of the tick, but not with the space after it. But thank you anyway.